# How to insert a new number into a list?

Tags: python, list

How do I add a new element in a list in python? For example, there is a list

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to update the list and insert 10.
it will become

```
lst = [10, 1, 2, 3]
```

which means the last element disappears and the older one moves back.

Comment: A bounded `deque` would be more appropriate than the linked duplicate, though.

Comment: Besides, this is not asking about inserting into a sorted list.

Comment: [Relevant](/questions/22340087/python-deque-difference-from-list), but probably not suitable as a duplicate for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
new_lst = [10] + lst[:-1]
# [10, 1, 2, 3]
```

This adds new element, here `10`, at first position and takes the list excluding the last element.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`list` methods](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `insert` and `pop`:

```
lst.insert(0, 10)  # lst is now [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lst.pop()  # lst is now [10, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Note**: Inserting items at the beginning of a Python list is not very efficient because Python lists are array lists. Instead you can use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects)(linked list) from the `collections` module. This will also allow you to provide a max size for the deque so the end element will always be bumped out:

```
from collections import deque

lst2 = deque(lst, maxlen=4)
lst2.appendleft(10)  # lst2 is now [10, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Works, though the question is a duplicate so its likely to be flagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a bounded `deque` instead of a list.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> d = deque([1,2,3,4], 4)
>>> d
deque([1, 2, 3, 4], maxlen=4)
>>> d.appendleft(10)
>>> d
deque([10, 1, 2, 3], maxlen=4)
```

A deque (double-ended queue) is like a queue, but rather than being optimized for appending to one end and removing from the other, it is optimized for appending and removing from either end. Setting a maximum length ensures that if you add an element to one end of a full deque, the element on the other end is automatically removed.